# Lucene.Net How to Filter Results and Exclude an Array of IDs?

Tags: c#, lucene.net

I am working on an application that will need to suggest to a user some books he might want to purchase. Typically, a user might have already purchased some books, and we do not know these books at design time. I want to suggest to the user books he has not purchased.

Since I am using lucene.net, I think what I need to do is to exclude the books the user has already purchased from the result to display to the user. So I could exclude an arbitrary (array) of BookIds the user has already purchase.

Is it possible to achieve this in Lucene.NET? Could you please provide sample code if possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the number of purchased books is small you can just add them to the query (... AND NOT bookid:1 AND NOT bookid:2 ... etc).

```
Query mainQuery = new Query();

        // you code here...


        if (purchasedBooks.Count > 0)
        {
            BooleanQuery filterPurchasedBooksQuery = new BooleanQuery();

            foreach (int bookId in purchasedBooks)
            {
                filterPurchasedBooksQuery.Add(new TermQuery(new Term("BookId", bookId.ToString())), Occur.MUST_NOT);
            }

            Query.Add(filterPurchasedBooksQuery, Occur.MUST);
        }

        // do search
```

If the number of purchased books is large you don't want to do it (performance wise) and you should write you own collector (override you current collector) and discard the purchased books.

```
   public abstract class YOURCollector : WHATEVER_COLLECTOER_THAT_YOU_ARE_USING
    {
        public List<int> PurchasedBooks { get; set; }

        public int?[] bookIds;

        public override void SetNextReader(IndexReader reader, int base_Renamed)
        {
            docBase = base_Renamed;
            bookIds = SingleFieldCache.Default.GetInt32s(reader, "BookId");
        }

        public override void Collect(int doc)
        {
            if (bookIds[doc].HasValue
                && PurchasedBooks.Contains(bookIds[doc].Value) == false)
            {
                base.Collect(doc);
            }
            else
            {
                // book already purchased...
            }
        }
    }
```

The code examples here are only examples, not a working code(!), i'm sure you can continue from here...

Comment: Hello Omri. Thanks for the code. But I cant seem to find SingleFieldCache? Where is it located? It is not in Lucene is it?

Comment: O.. you can find SingleFieldCache here (github.com/devhost/Corelicious/blob/master/Corelicious.Lucene/…) or you can use lucene builtin fields cache: "FieldCache_Fields.DEFAULT.GetInts".